# Short C++ program to increment characters in input

Tags: c++, string

So I know this program is simple, but I just need a little help. The task is to write a short program where I get the user input and the output should print the first character once and the second character twice, and the third character thrice, and so on.

example input: `abcd`

example output: `abbcccdddd`

Comment: [The Answer.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1428/761)

Comment: I have figured it out! I was using strlen and got a lot of errors! Tried a nested loop and continued getting errors

Comment: @Teebee It's still homework.... also if you're looking at exams that contain this type of problem then most people will also believe it's homework, you're sort of lucky that someone decided to post code as this would usually get closed or you would at least have to provide some code to prove you actually even tried (which in your case doesn't look like it)

Answer (score 1):

Well, normally I don't just write code for people, but here you go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::string in;
    std::cin >> in;

    for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << std::string(i + 1, in[i]); // repeat in[i] "i+1" times
    }

    // print newline
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This reads one string of input from the standard input stream, then loops over all the characters and outputs the character at `i` `i+1` times (because iterables start with index `0` in C++, usually, which is the case with strings). Then it prints out a newline and quits.

Comment: teach a man to fish (and all that).....

Comment: @Mitch: I tried to explain a bit what I did, but I'm not a teacher.

Comment: your code was most helpful and I thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
int thisMany = 0;
char c;

while( cin >> c )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < thisMany; i++ )
        cout << c;

    thisMany++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple, unoptimized code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string input;

    // Get user input.
    std::cin >> input;

    // Go through each character in input string.
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i)
    {
        // Print the character i times.
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < i; ++i2)
        {
            std::cout << input[i];
        }
    }

    // Print newline.
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's simple solution with double loop.

let's have array with characters called c[]

and we have something like this

```
for(int i=1;i<length_of_string;i++)
{
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        putchar(c[i]);
}
```